# error using qplot with facets?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, statistics

I am trying to do a histogram with this data for an example of using ggplot2 to create graphics, and then i found out i cant do this histogram with facets using qplot command, i already do this kind of plot with another data, but now i trying again with this specific data i can not do it.

this is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x      = diamonds$price,
      geom   = "histogram",
      facets = .~diamonds$cut)
```

As you can see is actually really simple but it give me the error:

> Error: value for ‘cut’ not found

if you do a quick research you find out that there are price values for every level in the cut factor.

```
diamonds$price[diamonds$cut=="Fair"]
diamonds$price[diamonds$cut=="Good"]
diamonds$price[diamonds$cut=="Very Good"]
diamonds$price[diamonds$cut=="Premium"]
diamonds$price[diamonds$cut=="Ideal"]
```

i couldn't understand what is wrong.

this is another example. But this is working.

```
x <- rnorm(120,20,20)
y <- as.factor(c(rep("yo",60),rep("tu",60)))
df <- data.frame(x,y)
qplot(x = df$x, geom = "histogram", facets = .~df$y)
```

What is the different between this data? i can not see it.

This show me that variables class are the same in this two example

```
is.numeric(diamonds$price)
```

> [1] TRUE

```
is.numeric(x)
```

> [1] TRUE

```
is.factor(diamonds$cut)
```

> [1] TRUE

```
is.factor(y)
```

> [1] TRUE

Please help.

Comment: The problem seems to stem from using dollar sign notation in `qplot`.  Use the data argument to define the dataset instead, `data = diamonds`.  Then refer to the variable names directly, e.g., `facets = .~cut`.

Comment: qplot actually support the use of vector inside of a dataframe using the $ simbol. i will edit the post to show that.

Comment: your solution actually give me the plot but i still not understand what is wrong with the code, why works with the second example but not the first one?. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your `df` example doesn't work for me if `x` and `y` are only in the dataset and not in the global environment.  Remove them and use `df = data.frame(x = rnorm(120,20,20), y = as.factor(c(rep("yo",60),rep("tu",60))))` to see the difference.  You should be using the `data` argument in `qplot` to avoid these issues.

Comment: You are right, i never notice that. i did suppose qplot was reading the df$x and df$y, but is not, now i get it. Thanks, a lot. I really appreciate this.

Comment: pls don't use qplot. i spent a bit of time nuking most references to it from ggplot2 docs. in the long run you'll appreciate the full on ggplot2 syntax and get used to it more.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is based in [aosmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2461552/aosmith) help, thanks.

The problem is that qplot is actually not reading the df$x and df$y variables in example number 2:

```
library(ggplot2)    
x <- rnorm(120,20,20)
y <- as.factor(c(rep("yo",60),rep("tu",60)))
df <- data.frame(x,y)
qplot(x = df$x, geom = "histogram", facets = .~df$y)
```

In this example, qplot is readind the object x and y, created in the first two lines, it never use df$x or df$y.

So, in the example number 1:

```
qplot(x      = diamonds$price,
      geom   = "histogram",
      facets = .~diamonds$cut)
```

There is not price or cut object in the environment, that is why i get the error.

Solution: Using the argument `data =`

like this:

```
qplot(data = diamonds,
      x = price,
      geom = "histogram",
      facets = .~cut)
```

Comment: When I run the questioner's code, I get `Error: value for ‘diamonds’ not found` despite 'diamonds' being available for examination with `str` from the console. There's no error if the facet argument is omitted. This does not really contradict your main point that the data argument should be used.

Comment: i add the `library(ggplot2)` command to the answer. I dont get that error.

Comment: I already had  ggplot2_2.2.1 in my list of attached packages. (Notice that I said `diamonds` was visible to `str`.) `library(ggplot2)` has no effect.